# In z/OS CICS, can the result of an EMP executed during a TASK be retrieved by the COBOL program that executed the EMP?

Tags: zos, cics

In z/OS, I can define a user EMP (Event Monitor Point) in the CICS MCT (Monitor Control Table). For example, one EMP can start a CPU clock/timer and another EMP can halt the CPU clock. I can then "execute" each EMP from my COBOL program during a TASK that runs the program. Execution of EMP "no.1" will start the clock and execution of EMP "no.2" will halt the clock.

I know that the eventual value of the CPU clock will be saved as part of the SMF 110 record that is written after completion of the TASK.

My question is, can the current value of the CPU clock be retrieved in the COBOL program while the TASK is still in execution?

If so, which CICS statement will do this? and into which structure/layout and field will the clock be retrieved?

The reason I wish to know is because I want to measure the CPU time that it takes for a certain process to be performed by the program. The same process may be performed a number of times in one TASK and I want to use the same CPU clock to measure each time that the process is performed.

Thanks very much,

Danny

Answer (score 1):

EXEC CICS COLLECT STATISTICS MONITOR(EIBTASKN) SET (ADDRESS OF DFHMNTDS) can be used to retrieve a running task monitoring fields - as Danny pointed out in comment below.

DFHMCT TYPE=EMP macro with PERFORM=DELIVER may be fit for your purpose. It  causes the Performance class data accumulated for this task up to this point delivered to the monitoring buffers. See CICS document:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGMCP_5.5.0/reference/resources/macros/mct/emp.html

If you are on CICS TS V5.4 or later, you might consider to separate out the process that runs repeatedly to a transaction. Then use 'EXEC CICS RUN TRANSID CHILD' to start the transaction from the  current COBOL program/task, which will start the process as a child task with the CPU being measured for it. You can get the response back from the child task using 'EXEC CICS FETCH CHILD'.

For details of using the two APIs please see articles in CICS Developer Center: https://developer.ibm.com/cics/category/asynchronous-api/

Thanks & kind regards,
Jenny (CICS development, IBM Hursley Lab)

Comment: Hi Jenny,
Thanks for the detailed reply.
Our shop is on CICS 5.3.
When you say that DELIVER causes the data to be "delivered to the monitoring buffers" what does that actually mean? Can the data be accessed by the COBOL program while the TASK is still running or only offline by analyzing the SMF records that were created by the TASK?
I currently use the following commands. Could you please comment on this?
EXEC CICS PERFORM STATISTICS RECORD MONITOR
    RESP (EZ10-RC-CICS) RESP2  (EZ10-RC2-CICS)
END-EXEC

Comment: (sorry, my previous comment got cut) …
I currently use the following commands. Could you please comment on this?
EXEC CICS PERFORM STATISTICS RECORD MONITOR
    RESP (EZ10-RC-CICS) RESP2  (EZ10-RC2-CICS)
END-EXEC
EXEC CICS COLLECT STATISTICS SET (ADDRESS OF DFHMNTDS)       MONITOR(EIBTASKN)
    RESP (EZ10-RC-CICS) RESP2  (EZ10-RC2-CICS)
END-EXEC
After these commands, performed in the COBOL program while the TASK is still in progress, I can access the current values in DFHMNTDS fields. Specifically "current TASK CPU time".
Thanks,
Danny

Comment: Hi Danny, 
EXEC CICS PERFORM STATISTICS RECORD MONITOR causes CICS to write out a statistics record for the global statistics on the monitor function of CICS region. It doesn't seem to me that this is related to the task CPU time you are pursuing.

EXEC CICS COLLECT STATISTICS SET(ADDRESS OF DFHMNTDS) MONITOR(EIBTASKN) would serve the purpose of retrieving the running task's monitoring fields which are mapped by DFHMNTDS. 

"delivered to the monitoring buffers" means that the record is buffered in CICS and CICS will write them out to SMF once the buffer is accumulated with enough records.

Comment: CICS v5.3 has a task policy rule Time, its CPU time subtype can be used to define a threshold for the amount of processor time that is used by a user task. Depends on your goal, this might be of interesting to you. With this approach there is no need to change the COBOL program, nor turn monitoring on. For details, please see: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGMCP_5.3.0/com.ibm.cics.ts.productoverview.doc/concepts/policy-task-rules.html